# Wordpress: deploy 1 WP site per web app or all WP sites in 1 App service plan?

Tags: wordpress, azure-web-app-service

I used the "Create WordPress on App Service" in Azure to create a single Wordpress web app successfully. I need to create 14 more WP sites. If I use the "Create WordPress on App Service" for each site, it will create 14 Web apps, all under their own App service and each with their own database server (which will get expensive). My question is, what would be best practice?

1. Create unique App service and web app for each WP site
2. Create unique App service and web app for each WP site, but change database connection to use only one of the DB servers, and then delete the other DB servers that are created with each app (I don't need an entire DB server for each web app)
3. Create an APP service plan, then create Web Apps under this service plan and manually install and configure WP on the VMs?

I was going to go with option #2 - but seems like someone out there is hosting multiple WordPress sites on Azure and could recommend the best option.

Note that these will be low traffic sites. Thank you